# I was trying to deploy a Storage Account using ARM template. However, an error has been thrown. Can someone help me on this issue

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-storage-account

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "North Europe"
            
        },
        "storageaccountname": {
            "defaultValue": "storageforarm1910",
            "type": "string"
        },
        "storageaccounttype": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Standard_GRS"
        }
           
    },
    "functions": [],
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-01-01",
            "location": "[parameters('location')]",
            "name": "[parameters('storageaccountname')]",
            "kind": "FileStorage",
            "sku": "[parameters('storageaccounttype')]",
            "properties": {}
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

```
Error: 
{"code":"InvalidTemplate","message":"Deployment template parse failed: 'Error converting value \"Standard_GRS\" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ResourceStack.Common.Core.Definitions.Resources.ResourceSku'. Path ''.'."}
```

Comment: If I'm [looking at the right API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.compute.models.storageaccounttype?view=azure-dotnet), then `Standard_GRS` is not among the three valid values for that field.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to create Azure FileStorage account, the sku must be `Premium_LRS` or `Premium_ZRS`. For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#types-of-storage-accounts).
[image]

Besides,please note that if we use `Premium_ZRS`, we just can create the storage account in some regions. Regarding the region, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#zone-redundant-storage).
[image]